# How to clean up a ausername input from form

Tags: php

On my website i have a registration form where users started to input characters i do not like them to be able to user when registering. The preg_replace currently removes some of it but i wonder how i can make it remove other unwanted character like from the sample usernames that i pasted in bellow, the username should just end up as one line. "user.name" should be cleaned to "username".

```
$username            = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['username']));
$username            = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $username);

Sample usernames:
1: utra.dara
2: arijanaĆerdić
3: özgür
4: frédéricrobert
5: patricko'laoghair
6: orgo~~ 
7: Diego^
```

Comment: `$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $s);`

Comment: Don't clean it, reject it.

Comment: If you change the username they've entered, how will they know what their username ended up as? Even if you tell them, they won't get a username of their choice. Add validation and tell them that they are only allowed to use certain characters instead.